# QR code reader scanner for Blazor (webassembly client)

Tags: c#, qr-code, blazor, webassembly

Was looking for a way to access the camera/webcam from blazor (client webassembly) to create a QRcode reader. Any suggestions?

I've googled and looked in github for a qrcode scanner for blazor but had no success.

Comment: did you have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61981172/displaying-the-local-machine-camera-feed-in-a-blazor-web-assembly-app

Comment: @sddk seems a little hacky, might just work on edge browser. thanks anyway

Answer (score 11):

I made a Blazor nuget package to read QR Code.

Install package, 4 lines of code, you're done.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReactorBlazorQRCodeScanner/
or
https://github.com/YannVasseur35/ReactorBlazorQRCodeScanner

based onjsQR.js lib.

Comment: thanks, if only I knew 2 years ago...

Comment: Can you provide a readme file or an open-source demo?

Comment: hello, I forgot to include readme on last package. Source code are here https://github.com/YannVasseur35/ReactorBlazorQRCodeScanner

Answer (score 1):

I just created a simple PWA project using Dynamsoft JavaScript barcode SDK. If you don't mind it's a commercial SDK, you can try it out:
https://github.com/dynamsoft-dbr/javascript-barcode/tree/6.x/examples/pwa.

and

Here you find the library with lots of examples

https://github.com/zxing-js/library